# How Can An Animal Accumulate Karma?

Tags: karma, moksha, animals, ethics

If we take into consideration the behavior of certain  animals whose intelligence and perception are radically different from our human perspective (e.g. a flatworm , a jellyfish or even an *Amoeba*) how can this living being accumulate positive or negative Karma, given that we cannot classify their behavior according to our ethical standards. In other words, we cannot say that a jellyfish has behaved in an evil way, even if it has stung us! So, how can these creatures, who seem to act merely  according to their instinct, accumulate positive or negative karma?

Comment: The first mistake is you are confusing karma and ethics. Ethics are by product of Karma they are not Karma by themselves.

Comment: On the contrary the more conscious you become the less karma sticks to you. The more unconscious you become the more karma sticks to you. In fact Animals are so deep in karma that they cannot aspire for realization in that body. They need a human body to become conscious and dissolve karma to achieve liberation. When Amoeba eats an other organism it is committing karma.

Comment: Karma is just memory of your previous actions. Conscious or Unconcious. It remembers and it will play back.

Comment: animals don't accumulate karma.

Comment: Karma is not good or bad inherently, although some leads to more positive results.